# Python os.path is ntpath, how?

Tags: python, path, module, alias

Can someone tell me how Python "aliases" `os.path` to `ntpath`?

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path
<module 'ntpath' from 'C:\Python26\lib\ntpath.pyc'>
>>>
```

Comment: One of the really great things about the Python Standard Library is that you can look at the source. I really recommend poking around in there to see how stuff is done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at [os.py](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/os.py?annotate=77218), lines 55-67:

```
elif 'nt' in _names:
    name = 'nt'
    linesep = '\r\n'
    from nt import *
    try:
        from nt import _exit
    except ImportError:
        pass
    import ntpath as path

    import nt
    __all__.extend(_get_exports_list(nt))
    del nt
```

The `import ntpath as path` is the specific statement that causes `os.path` to be `ntpath` on your platforms (doubtlessly Windows).

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> import os as my_aliased_module
>>> my_aliased_module
<module 'os' from 'C:\Program Files\Python 2.6\lib\os.pyc'>
```

**EDIT:** And since `import` is a simple statement in Python, you can do neat stuff like:

```
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':
  import windows_module as my_module
else:
  import unix_module as my_module
```