# Python Import Error: No module named ntpath

Tags: python, odoo, windows-mobile

First of all let me say I'm new with python. I'm trying to run a python script on a Windows Mobile 6.1 Classic Device. I'm using Python CE to run python on the device. The script is from an Open Source ERP software (Odoo) that has a client for handheld barcode scanners.

In my first tests I got a bunch of errors for missing modules but I've been able to manually install them on the device but now I get

```
    Traceback (innermost last):
    Cant import traceback
    <type 'exceptions.ImportError''>: No Module named ntpath
```

I've been looking for info on internet and the only things I found is that it has something to do with the os.path function in the file os.py of python setup. And with managing files in the code. 
I've tried to manually change all the paths and variables in the code to set them manually with a string and using \\ instead of / or \ but I can't get rid of this error.

Comment: `ntpath` is a built-in module, it is the Windows-specific implementation of the `os.path` module. It probably is missing because you don't have a filesystem.

Comment: In the os.py file I can see code refering to os.path and ntpath so I guess that at least the code for the module isn't missing at all? And you are talking about a filesystem inside python or the script or for the entire OS, I don't get that.

Comment: Ah, no, I confused modules; `ntpath.py` is a pure-Python module. I'm not sure why Python CE doesn't include that module, perhaps the developers of Python CE didn't expect you to need to use filesystem functions.

Comment: You should be able to fix that, as all the python code is ascii (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126301/python-os-path-is-ntpath-how). If python can not load the module, the question is where the module file is located, is that in the PATH? Here are general remarks for WinCE: WinCE has no drive letters; WinCE does not have a 'current dir'. For info on writing and loading moduls, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Where did you load pythonce from? Here: http://pythonce.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pythonce/pythonce/Lib/

Comment: Maybe, this could be useful: https://pypi.org/project/path.py/